# C++ .NET VisibleChanged Called if parent is set visible, but not if parent is set not visible

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I got a form containing a panel, that itself contain a label. A attach to the VisibleChanged of the label. I add two button to the form. One that set the Visible of the Panel to true, and the other that set the same property to false.
When I click the visible button, the VisibleChanged event is thrown. When I hide the panel, the event is not launched. What am I doing wrong.

Here is the code of my form.

```
#pragma once

namespace CLRConsoleApplication1 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for MyForm
/// </summary>
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~MyForm()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Panel^  panel1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  ShowButton;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  HideButton;
protected: 

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->panel1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Panel());
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->ShowButton = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->HideButton = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->panel1->SuspendLayout();
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this->panel1->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->panel1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(32, 32);
        this->panel1->Name = L"panel1";
        this->panel1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(200, 108);
        this->panel1->TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(60, 38);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 13);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->label1->Text = L"label1";
        this->label1->VisibleChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::label1_VisibleChanged);
        // 
        // ShowButton
        // 
        this->ShowButton->Location = System::Drawing::Point(32, 162);
        this->ShowButton->Name = L"ShowButton";
        this->ShowButton->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->ShowButton->TabIndex = 1;
        this->ShowButton->Text = L"Show";
        this->ShowButton->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->ShowButton->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::ShowButton_Click);
        // 
        // HideButton
        // 
        this->HideButton->Location = System::Drawing::Point(157, 162);
        this->HideButton->Name = L"HideButton";
        this->HideButton->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->HideButton->TabIndex = 2;
        this->HideButton->Text = L"Hide";
        this->HideButton->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->HideButton->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::HideButton_Click);
        // 
        // MyForm
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
        this->Controls->Add(this->HideButton);
        this->Controls->Add(this->ShowButton);
        this->Controls->Add(this->panel1);
        this->Name = L"MyForm";
        this->Text = L"MyForm";
        this->panel1->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->panel1->PerformLayout();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void label1_VisibleChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show( "label1_VisibleChanged: " + label1->Visible );
         }
private: System::Void HideButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             panel1->Visible = false;
         }
private: System::Void ShowButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             panel1->Visible = true;
         }
};
}
```

PS. I am using Visual Studio 2012 Update 4.

Edit: Here is bit more information. I have access to a control. Another project have access to the same control, and put in inside a panel inside a form. Then then hide or show the panel depending on user request.
On my side, I don't know the panel, only the control. I want to know when the control become visible or hidden, because I need to change some related control accordingly.

Comment: This is not C++, but C++/CLI using WinForms. I have updated the tags to reflect this.

Comment: Your code did not change the label's Visible property.  You merely hid the label by hiding its parent.  If you want the event to fire then you'd have to set label1->Visible = false;  Beware that the Visible property is quirky, setting it to *true* doesn't not guarantee that you get a *true* back when you read the property.  The setter gives the *intent* to be visible, the getter returns whether it is *actually* visible.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I only change the parent. In this case, for only a label, I could change it, but it is merely a small program to show the problem I got in a bigger application were I can't directly change the control inside a panel.

Comment: That's the bigger problem with questions like this, they don't show us *why* the VisibleChanged event is important to you.  I never use it so can't guess at it either.  We can't give you a workaround when you don't tell us.

Comment: Have a look at `SetVisibleCore` and the conditions under which it gets called.  You could just also subscribe to the `VisibleChanged` event for all the parent controls as well.

Comment: @HansPassant: Why is there no `IsVisible` that returns the actual visible-state of the control?, and the `Visible` property returns exactly what was set to it? Same applies to `Enabled`. I guess this design decision has caused many headaches among developers.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Subscribing to all parent controls is an ugly workaround. If the control itself is moved to another parent, you'd have to revert all subscriptions. Also, I would never go beyond the parent if it was an UserControl. But what if the visibility is changed on the parent of the UserControl? As I wrote to Hans, an `IsVisible {get;}` is missing.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss: You may be interested to know that the corresponding OS function has to walk all the parents as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-iswindowvisible

Comment: @BenVoigt: yes, this probably is the only correct solution, but this would be done *on demand* every time it is queried, and not by subscribing, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have

```
label1->VisibleChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::label1_VisibleChanged);
```

add also

```
panel1->VisibleChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::label1_VisibleChanged);
```

and see if you get the desired results.